# Mono - VBNC90013: Error finding class 'Sub Main'

Tags: vb.net, mono

I have a file that contains this

```
Module MainModule
    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("hello")
    End Sub
End Module
```

When I compile this using `vbnc MainModule.vb` it compiles just fine.

However, I have a `.vbproj` file that was created in VisualStudio. And when I run `xbuild` in my project directory, I get the aforemenetioned error:

```
 VBNC90013: Error finding class 'Sub Main' with the Main function, found 0 classes with this name.
```

It appears that if I comment out the `<StartupObject>Sub Main</StartupObject>` that it will compile.

Is this a bug in Mono, or just something to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the project file, it should say `<StartupObject>MainModule</StartupObject>`.

The question is of course how you ended up with such a project file in the first place - can you [file a bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) if you can reproduce how you ended up with such a project file?